# Make terminal talk from a ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

There is a operation of terminal (osx) called say. If I type say hello, the terminal uses voice control to say hello.

I want to access this command from my ruby script. Any idea how I can say hello from my ruby script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simplistic way to call commands from ruby is with backticks.

For example,

```
def say_hello
    `say hello`
end
```

Would run the command `say hello` in terminal.

Testing this in IRB causes the computer to say "Hello".

You might want to look into alternate methods of calling the command line though, as backticks aren't the most secure.